# Where to put audio files when Exporting a Processing.org Application for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, audio, export, processing

I am working on a Mac and trying to export my application for use on a Mac. I have two small audio files that I access in my application, but those files do not get copied over into the application.macosx folder.

When I am running the application on my computer, I can copy the audio files into the application.macosx folder and the application works. If I do not copy the audio files into the application.macosx folder, the application will not fully launch.

I am looking for a way to include these audio files so I only have to send the use the application file. I do not want to send them the application.macosx folder. I have tried adding the audio files to every location inside the "application package", but nothing has worked.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your confusion is a wee bit confusing. Are those audio files constant and *never* changing?  If so, why couldn't you simply keep the audio files within the Resources folder of your application package?

Comment: The audio files do not change. I have a folder named 'myproject' where I keep all the Processing files and the audio files. Then I export the application and the audio files do not get included in the exported application. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to create a "resources" folder somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... here's what you need to do.

In older times (I'm thinking pre-Xcode 4), when creating new applications on the Macintosh, there would automatically be a "Resources" folder created where one could drop images, sound files, etc. that the Macintosh application would use.  ("Resources" themselves are a hold-over from "classic MacOS" days, when almost everything was embedded into .rsrc files... but I digress).

Now, instead of "Resources", Xcode 4 creates a "Supporting Files" group when a new Macintosh app project is set up.

So, to take care of your issue, import or drag & drop your audio files into this "Supporting Files" group in your project and then they should end up in your application package no problem.  When I built this test app, the .wav file ended up in the "Resources" folder of the application package.

I copied a .wav file that I had lying around into a test project and here is what it looks like:
[image: sound files go into supporting files]

I hope my answer helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative path to the sketch(wherever that might execute). There's a built in property called `sketchPath` is quite handy for this. You might place the file one level above the sketch path for example:

```
String path = sketchPath+"/../yourFile.mp3";
```

it's up to you. To check if the path is correct you could try something like:

```
println("does " + path + " exist? : " + new File(path).exists());
```

Another idea is to use the [selectInput()](http://processing.org/reference/selectInput_.html) which will prompt for the file location. It might be handy to try using the sketchPath() function (which should format a path relative to the sketch) on the String returned by selectInput().